# Secure remote SQL Server connections

Tags: sql-server, security, sql, remote-access, windows-sbs

I have a question. We develop client-server software using SQL Server on our clients networks. We are wanting to create a web portal that links into this SQL Server database but are unaware of the best practice when it comes to allowing remote SQL Server access.

We know that DMZs are often used for this sort of thing but are wondering what other methods there are?

A little bit of background. The sotware is a desktops app that connects to a SQL Server DB often running on a small business server (but not always). We would like to write a web app in PHP that can connect to each database on the clients newtworks.

Any info most appreciated,

Billy

Answer (score 1):

My own personal preference would be ipsec or Openvpn VPNs, but this might be overkill. OpenVPN tends to be easier to deploy, and works on every version of Windows that I've ever tried.